# Vuetify Expansion Panels with Virtual Scroll

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a dynamic list of expansion panels and I want to use a virtual scroll on them as the list can be quit big

Here is my example

https://codepen.io/amaieras/pen/XWVBoWo?editors=1010

```
<v-expansion-panels>
  <v-virtual-scroll
     :items="items"
     height="300"
     item-height="64">
       <template v-slot:default="{ item }">
         <v-expansion-panel>
           <v-expansion-panel-header>
                    Item
             </v-expansion-panel-header>
             <v-expansion-panel-content>
               some content
             </v-expansion-panel-content>
           </v-expansion-panel>
  </v-virtual-scroll>
</v-expansion-panels>
```

The problem is that when expanding one panel it is not well displayed due to the position absolute of the virtual item.

I want to make the expansion work as expected

Mainly the problem is how to make a child of an absolute element move the parent's sibling down on expand